# SolrCloud Re-Indexing routing issue

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

I am updating SolrCloud from version 4.8.1 to version 5.2.1 and I know that a full re-index is suggested in these cases. Unfortunately in my case, the only way to perform it is to use my current index as data source, by reading documents from my current collection and re-indexing them inside a new collection. I am aware that this is not the suggested procedure, but I really don't have any other way to perform a full re-index.
So, I built my own java code to automatically perform this process. Here the pseudo-code:

```
CloudSolrClient serverOutput = new CloudSolrClient(...);
serverOutput.setDefaultCollection(...);
List<SolrInputDocument> buffer = new ArrayList<>(bufferSize);
int currentIndex = 0;
int totalNumberOfDocs = ...;
while (currentIndex < totalNumberOfDocs) {
        SolrDocumentList solrDocumentList = getChunkOfSolrDocument(currentIndex); //this returns a chunk of documents from my old collection
        currentIndex += solrDocumentList.size();

        for(int i=0; i < solrDocumentList.size(); i++){
            SolrDocument solrDoc = solrDocumentList.get(i);
            SolrInputDocument solrInputDoc = org.apache.solr.client.solrj.util.ClientUtils.toSolrInputDocument(solrDoc);
            solrInputDoc.removeField("_version_");
            buffer.add(solrInputDoc);
        }

    if (buffer.size() > bufferSize) {
        try {
            for (SolrInputDocument doc : buffer) {
                serverOutput.add(doc);
            }
            serverOutput.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ...
        } finally {
            buffer.clear();
        }
    }
}

if (!buffer.isEmpty()) {
    try {
        for (SolrInputDocument doc : buffer) {
            serverOutput.add(doc);
        }
        serverOutput.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ...
    } finally {
        buffer.clear();
    }
}
```

Both my old and new collections use the Solr Cloud compositeId router. My old collection has 4 shards, while the new collection has 16 shards. The old collection has these hash ranges:

```
  "shard1" ==> "range":"80000000-bfffffff",
  "shard2" ==> "range":"c0000000-ffffffff",
  "shard3" ==> "range":"0-3fffffff",
  "shard4" ==> "range":"40000000-7fffffff"
```

The new collection has these hash ranges:

```
  "shard1" ==> "range":"80000000-8fffffff",
  "shard2" ==> "range":"90000000-9fffffff",
  "shard3" ==> "range":"a0000000-afffffff",
  "shard4" ==> "range":"b0000000-bfffffff",
  "shard5" ==> "range":"c0000000-cfffffff",
  "shard6" ==> "range":"d0000000-dfffffff",
  "shard7" ==> "range":"e0000000-efffffff",
  "shard8" ==> "range":"f0000000-ffffffff",
  "shard9" ==> "range":"0-fffffff",
  "shard10" ==> "range":"10000000-1fffffff",
  "shard11" ==> "range":"20000000-2fffffff",
  "shard12" ==> "range":"30000000-3fffffff",
  "shard13" ==> "range":"40000000-4fffffff",
  "shard14" ==> "range":"50000000-5fffffff",
  "shard15" ==> "range":"60000000-6fffffff",
  "shard16" ==> "range":"70000000-7fffffff"
```

This code can successfully import my documents inside the new collection but, for some reason, it imports the documents only inside 4 shards of my 16-shards collection. So, at the end of the process, my new collection contains the same documents of my old collection, but my new collection has 4 shards filled of documents and 12 shards empty.

I also tried to use a 'whitelist' of fields, specifying the same fields that I have inside my schema, doing a solrInputDoc.removeField for any other field but I have the same result. I even tried to create an empty 4 shards collection, double check that the hash ranges are **the same in both the collections**, then split the shards until I have 16 shards and then delete the 'original' shards and run my code: I still have 4 shards filled and 12 shards empty.

Do you know why documents are not properly distributed among all the 16 shards?

Thank you very much guys.

**EDIT**: all my fields have *stored="true"*

**EDIT2**: it seems that optimize your index is enough if you want update all the segments to the file format of the updated version of Lucene. However, I still want to solve this 'routing' issue since it can be a workaround for [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-5808) open bug

Comment: I don't think you will have to reindex the data for upgrading the solr cloud. Why don't you upgrade node by node..? If not worst case create collections in new solr and copy data folder from each of the shards you have in current one, still better than reindexing

Comment: Worst case if you still want to go with your approach, please create only 4 shards in the new collection and export the data and then use shard split to achieve 16 shards. But yes, there will be a headache an network overhead in moving to different nodes so as to balance the cluster

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. 
1) I read that it's suggested to re-index after a version upgrade: I am trying to find the source on which it is described
2) I already tried this approach: I created a collection with 1 single shard, tried to move about 10k documents with the code I described, then splitted the shard: it created the 2 shards but copied all the documents inside one of them, leaving the other one empty. I really don't know why. I can try with 4 shards but I believe the result will be to have only 4 shards filled by the documents.

Comment: I have basically tried for 20 million records of 300 GB by splitting them from one shard(single core solr) to 5.2.1 2 shards. It was fine except that it took around 12 hours to create a replica. So I too re indexed the data. I would still say re indexing is not required as that will not be the case with company's with billions of records

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use the 'split shard' due to the open bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-5808

Comment: The difference between my versions is not so high, but on this [link](http://grokbase.com/t/lucene/solr-user/1324tmrxpk/upgrading-indexes-from-solr-1-4-1-to-4-1-0), for instance, it's recommended a full reindex after a Solr upgrade.
Also this [link](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Solr-3-1-Upgrade-Reindex-necessary-td2919679.html) contains some information about it.

It seems enough to just optimize the index from this point of view. However, I was trying to workaround the open bug SOLR-5808 with my reindexing process, so I am still interested in solving the 'routing' issue I have.

Comment: I have no comments for your current issue, even I am looking forward for an solution. Let us see the inputs from others

Comment: I just read your message as "Both my old and new collections use the Solr Cloud compositeId router." Doe this mean you decide the shard in which the doc has to belong? If that is the case you don't need to deal with hash ranges. during doc indexing, you will have to change the unique id by prefixing with the shard number. Have you done that?

Comment: Let me copy and paste from the documentation which explains it better than me:
There are two basic document-routing strategies supported by SolrCloud: compositeId (default) and implicit. The default compositeId router computes a numeric hash of the unique ID field in a document and assigns the document to the shard whose range includes the computed hash value.

Comment: as per my understanding default is based on hash key of id. Please refer https://lucidworks.com/blog/solr-cloud-document-routing/

Comment: Yes, that's why I don't understand why documents are not properly distributed among different shards. Once Solr knows the number of shards, it assigns each shard a range of 32-bit hash values. The 32-bit hash range is split evenly between each shard. Solr uses the MurmurHash algorithm that creates an even distribution of hash values, which keeps the number of documents in each shard roughly balanced. So, when you split your ranges from 4 to 16,you expect to have roughly the 25% of the original documents on each shard. Instead, I am having 50% of docs in 4 shards and 0% inside the other shards.

Comment: Okay got it. I have not seen this behavior luckily in my system so far. Let us hear some inputs from experts on this

Comment: Sorry guys, percentages are clearly wrong. I meant that when you split your ranges from 4 to 16, you expect to have roughly the 1/16 of the original documents on each shard. Instead, my documents are distributed only among 4 shards and the other 12 shards remain empty.